# Better way of implementing if statement in a loop

Tags: for-loop, optimization, plsql, procedure

I have a simple code in PL/SQL which I wish to optimize. I have this procedure that accepts two parameters, param1(table id) and param2(date). What it does is it iterates through the table and checks if param2 is in between the value of columns fld_date1 and fld_date2. If it does, it executes another logic. The table could no longer accept anymore parameters aside form the table id. Below is the snippet

```
procedure proc1(
  param1                                     id table
 ,param2                                        date
)
is
begin
   for n in tab(param1).row_list loop
     if  param2 >= n.fld_date1
     and param2 <= n.n.fld_date2 then
       (...);
     end if;
   end loop;
end proc1;
```

This one works but I think maybe some of you could think of a better version of this. My worries is that of the performance iterating thru a large number of rows. Any help/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not just use a SELECT to get the relevant records and then have your logic operate on that? looks to me like you are forcing a table scan for no reason.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but direct access to the table is not permitted.

Comment: Are you sure that `tab(param1).row_list` , `param1   id table` is valid `pl/sql` syntax?

Comment: What constitutes a "large number of rows"? Have you run any tests to see if you DO have a performance issue?  Iterating through a collection is very very fast. Likely the time it takes to BUILD this collection from your table will be much larger than the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "between" to check if date falls in a range rather than checking 2 conditions.

Comment: looks like syntactic sugar. My guess is that under the hood the same checks are still preformed.